# jQuery click event handler not firing

Tags: jquery

I had a more robust page, but the jQuery is not firing and I have no idea why! In both Firefox and Chrome, there's nothing showing in the console. Please help me see what my fried brain cannot see:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("ready!");

            $("#launch_windows").click(function(){
                console.log('launching');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="launch_windows" value="Launch" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure there was nothing in the console? You haven't included `jquery.js` in your page...

Comment: You didn't include jquery library man???

Comment: Include a jquery reference.

Comment: Also, the `meta` tag should be inside the `head`

Comment: i included the jquery library (doh!) and moved the meta tag inside the head and still nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language attribute is deprecated [based on the mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

> language 
>   Like the type attribute, this attribute identifies the scripting language in use. Unlike the type attribute, however, this attribute’s possible values were never standardized. The type attribute should be used instead.

If you want to use `language` you need to use `javascript` (without the `text/`) as indicated in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533940(v=vs.85).aspx)

Use the `type` attribute instead.

> This attribute identifies the scripting language of code embedded within a script element or referenced via the element’s src attribute. This is specified as a MIME type; examples of supported MIME types include text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/javascript, and application/ecmascript. If this attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript.

If I change your mark up to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

your code either works or shows errors in the Development Console. As can be learned from the documentation you could also leave the type out. In that case the browser assumes the content in the script tag is javascript

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").click(function(){
            console.log('clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="test">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```